# Create contact list for various subsites

Tags: sharepoint-server

Are there webparts that are free or available to license that will allow us to create a filtered contact list, that would pull data from a larger Sharepoint list, to display on a department subsite?  For example, to display the Marketing contacts on the Marketing page.  This would be for a Sharepoint on-premise version.  Ideally, a webpart similar to the old Content Query Tool webpart that would show items from a list on different subsites.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this atricle to show list from parent site in Sub Site:
[SharePoint 2016: Show List From Parent Site In Sub Site](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/#:%7E:text=Steps%201%20Open%20your%20Parent%20Site%20via%20SharePoint,that%20you%20need%20to%20show%20on%20the%20subsite.)

Comment: Thank you for sharing - I'll take a look.  Will this work in a Sharepoint 2019 on-prem version, using modern pages?